# Waiting till a transaction completes in NDB

Tags: transactions, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm working on a project and I have a situation where the I send a POST request which is a transaction (a must requirement). Immediately after POST request, I redirect to a page where I have to fetch the same data but I am getting the old data back. Is there a way for my GET request to wait until the transaction completes. I don't want to use any hacky solution like `sleep()`

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be academic example Asynchronous Programming. You didn't mention any particular technology you are using, but its available in all commonly used programing languages. The Promise mechanism known in JS might be good example. If you don't know nothing about it you can just google for `"Asynchronous Programming" + <your technology>`. When it comes datastore Google has lot of nice APIs for node.js, java and python and others. You can check here https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries

Comment: Thats good. JS has tones of tutorials over  the net i found something like that https://www.fullstackreact.com/30-days-of-react/day-14/ i hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

I imagine your POST handler is not just launching [datastore async ops](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/async) inside the transaction and return without waiting for their completion (which is possible but most likely would defeat the purpose of using the transaction in the first place). In other words your problem isn't actually related to the transaction (or rather what the transaction is trying to achieve) not being finished by the time the POST request handler execution completes.

If your GET request handler obtains the data via regular queries it may miss the updates from the POST request handler because of 2 possible reasons:

1. the [datastore eventual consistency](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore/)
2. the (unspecified) amount of time it takes for the change to propagate to the datastore index used by the queries

The typical approach for addressing the first problem is modifying the GET handler queries into `keys_only` queries and then obtaining the actual entity content by direct key lookups, which is strongly consistent. But this is useless if your app is also sensitive to the second problem (for example if the expected entity key isn't even present in the list of keys returned).

The only way I can think of the second problem can be addressed is to pass enough information (from the POST request handler) to the GET request handler to allow it to obtain the data without making use of queries (or to correct/complete the potentially stale info obtained from queries, but that's not trivial). For example passing the keys or key IDs of the entities updated in the transaction. Either via some user session data or maybe as request parameters. Or via memcache (but keep in mind that the memcache info can dissapear at any time, so this might not work in all cases)